# How to migrate from material-ui to mui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hello everybody.
I already have installed material-ui since a long time in my project based on React. Today that i needed a component from material noticed that now is called mui. How can i migrate or have both in my project?

First I just installed mui like this

**yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled**

And it came down with many errors from materia-ui.
Then I updated material-ui library? like this

**yarn add @material-ui/core@next @emotion/react @emotion/styled**

But have them both or just one of the steps didn't really work. What can I do?

Comment: https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/

Comment: You don't need `@material-ui/...` packages if you use v5, they are for v4 or v5 in beta. Can you add the error messages?